# Node+Express jest testing using Redis (without mocks)

Tags: node.js, express, redis, jestjs, supertest

My team and I are currently building a Node service using Express. In order to setup Redis and verify it is working, we created two simple GET and POST endpoints, one to retrieve data by key and another one to set the information. I will only show the GET one as it is the first one we are testing (without success).

This is the Redis service `redis.service.js` we have:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const ScaInfo = require("../models/sca-info.model");

let redisClient;

/**
 * Creates a Redis connection.
 */
const connect = async () => {
  let redisConf = {
    socket: {
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: process.env.REDIS_PORT
    }
  }
  redisClient = redis.createClient(redisConf);
  redisClient.on("error", (error) => logger.error(`Redis client: ${error}`));
  await redisClient.connect();
};

/**
 * Ends Redis connection.
 */
const disconnect = async () => {
  await redisClient.disconnect();
}

/**
 * Retrieves Redis data from a specific key
 * @param {*} key : Redis identifier of the data to retrieve
 */
const getData = async (key) => {
  let result = await redisClient.hGetAll(key);
  return result;
}
```

This is the code run when we receive a GET request:

```
const redisService = require('../services/redis.service');

/**
 * Retrieves Redis key received as URL param
 * @param {*} req: Request information with URL param
 * @param {*} res: Response information with status code
 */
const getScaInfo = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let result = await redisService.getData(req.params.operationId);
        res.status(result && Object.keys(result).length ? 200 : 404).send(result);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ code: 500, key: 'internal-error', message: 'Internal error' });
    }
}
```

This is the express setup we have in `app.js`:

```
const express = require("express");

const { redisRouter } = require("./routes/redis.routes");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/redis", redisRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

And finally this is how we set it up in `index.js`. This is the entry file that runs the application itself:

```
const app = require("./app/app");
const redisService = require('./app/services/redis.service');

const setup = async () => {
  await redisService.connect();

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT} ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
  });
}

setup();
```

This works perfectly fine when running the service as usual, returning the data we have in the Redis Cache. However, it is not working in our test:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const assert = require('assert');
const app = require('../app/app');
const redisService = require('../app/services/redis.service');

beforeEach(async () => {
    console.log('Before each');
    await redisService.connect();
});

afterEach(async () => {
    console.log('After each');
    await redisService.disconnect();
});

describe('testing redis endpoints', () => {
    test('GET key', async () => {
        request(app)
            .get('/redis/test')
            .expect(404)
            .then(response => {
                assert(response.body == {});
            });
    });
});
```

We receive an error when the code tries to reach to Redis in the GET endpoint.

We tried several combinations of the jest beforeEach/beforeAll/etc. operations to set Redis up, but none worked.

Adding

```
if (!redisClient.isReady && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  redisClient.connect();
}
```

before the redis GET operation made it work, but the purpose of the test is to check the endpoint works as it is.

We believe the issue has to do with some context difference between the redisClient that is being connected and disconnected in the before and after operations, and the one called by the endpoint itself, but we are not sure.

How can we solve this issue? It will be a problem in the future if we don't manage to test our redis endpoints.

Comment: "We receive an error when the code tries to reach to Redis in the GET endpoint." -- and the error is? But I'm not sure how this makes sense--the app already opens a Redis connection, why do it in the test as well?

Comment: @DaveNewton The error from redisClient.hGetAll(key) we get is just an Exception but is doesn't return any information when capturing the exception, just "{}" (it happened outside the tests too when the connection was not working when running the local service as normal).

The redisClient.connection() is required in the tests because it is done in index.js in the normal code, and that is not run in the tests. The tests receives app.js directly (the express application with the setup). Even so, if we added the clientService.connection() inside app.js, the connection didn't work either.